# Volley string request is not working in Kotlin

Tags: php, json, kotlin, singleton, android-volley

Hi guys I'm stuck with this problem for a couple of weeks now, I hope u can help me with that.
So I have a local server with database(PHPMyadmin + MySQL), I have a request that I call as follows http://localhost/WebApi/v1/?op=addBars with Postman  I pass 4 values with this request first_name, Last_name, Email and Pass and they will be saved in then database  and it works fine.
but when I try to send data to database with Volley in Kotlin: I don;t get any answer and no error as well
so this how my V1.php looks like

```
case 'addBars':
                if(isset($_POST['Email']) && isset($_POST['Pass']) && isset($_POST['First_Name'])&& isset($_POST['Last_Name'])){
                    $db = new DbOperation(); 
                    if($db->createBars($_POST['Email'], $_POST['Pass'],$_POST['First_Name'], $_POST['Last_Name'])){
                        $response['error'] = false;
                        $response['message'] = 'Bars added successfully';
                    }else{
                        $response['error'] = true;
                        $response['message'] = 'Could not add Bars';
            }                  
                }else{
                    $response['error'] = true; 
                    $response['message'] = 'Required Parameters are missing';
                }
            break;
```

this also how the create bars looks like in DbOperation.php

```
    public function createBars($Email,$Pass,$First_Name,$Last_Name){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO Bars (Email, Pass,First_Name,Last_Name) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $Email, $Pass,$First_Name,$Last_Name);
        if($stmt->execute())
            return true; 
        return false; 
    }
```

This is also how I use the Volley request in Kotlin

```
           val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, EndPoints.URL_ADD_Bars,
                Response.Listener { response ->
                    try {
                        
                        val obj = (response)
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext ,"test "+obj+"" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                       // Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "response,"+response.toString()+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                },

                object : Response.ErrorListener {
                    override fun onErrorResponse(volleyError: VolleyError) {
                         Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "error,"+volleyError.toString()+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    }
                })
            
            {
                @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
                override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                    val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                    params.put("Email",Email)
                    params.put("Pass",Pass)
                    params.put("First_Name",First_Name)
                    params.put("Last_Name",Last_Name)
                    return params
                }
        }

        //adding request to queue
        VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)}
```

and that is how my EndPoints looks like

```
object EndPoints {
    private val URL_ROOT = "https://192.130.180.209/WebApi/v1/?op="
    val URL_ADD_Bars = URL_ROOT + "addBars"
    val URL_GET_Bars = URL_ROOT + "getBars"
    val URL_Bars_info = URL_ROOT + "Bars_info"

    val URL_Bars_Listing = URL_ROOT + "Bars_Listing"

    val URL_Bars_Listing_name_adress = URL_ROOT + "Bars_Listing_name_adress"
    val URL_Bars_info_update_api = URL_ROOT + "Bars_info_update_api"

}
```

I will be so grateful if u can help me with that :) and I f u have any questions just hit me up
I'm using  volley:1.1.0
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

Comment: are you can upload file PHP in the server or host? So I can test?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys I Solved the Problem I was just giving the wrong IP Adresse in my endpoint